# Swift Pass Data to Javascript

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to pass data from my swift file in an iOS app to a javascript file that I have. I looked up `evaluateJavaScript` method and it is not working. Not sure what Im doing wrong. Here is what I am trying. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var webView: WKWebView
let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let loginScriptURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("addComment", ofType: "js")
let addCommentMessageHandler = "addComment"

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRectZero, configuration: config)
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
    config.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: addCommentMessageHandler)
    let scriptContent = try? String(contentsOfFile:loginScriptURL!, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptContent!, injectionTime: .AtDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
    config.userContentController.addUserScript(script)
    webView.evaluateJavaScript("storeAndShow( \(DataService.shared.theComment) )",
        completionHandler: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpView()
}

func setUpView() {
    view.addSubview(webView)
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let height = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: -44)
    let width = NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    view.addConstraints([height, width])

    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string:"https://blah.com)!))
}
```

As you can see I am trying to call storeAndShow with some data. The storeAndShow method is in my javascript file.

Comment: Have you set up the view as a WKScriptMessageHandler delegate and implemented the didReceiveScriptMessage handler to process results?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:) says that:

> **Discussion**
>
> The method sends the result of the script evaluation (or an error) to the completion handler.

But you are passing `nil` to the completion handler. You should check if it is retuning an error, maybe there is more information there about the problem.